# HTML/CSS cropping images

Tags: html, css, image, layout, crop

So I have a logo on my site and the problem is when you hover under it or around it you can still click it. I want it only to be clickable once on it.

[www.theanimedatabase.com](http://www.theanimedatabase.com)

The logo is found in the top right!

Comment: You really should just crop your image in an image editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on your logo and click "Inspect Element", you will be able to see the area of your image is actually 200px x 200px.

Try crop away your logo extra height at the bottom (and extra height on the top I am guessing you have extra height at the top as well because you set the header img margin-top as -68px to push your logo upwards) so that the total height of your logo is 70px. Which will match with your header.

Next, change this in your css:

```
header img {
    margin-top: -68px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left auto;
}
```

to:

```
 header img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left auto;
}
```

Comment: So basically I have to go back to photoshop, as when i change it does the same thing but smaller...?

Comment: Yes go back to photoshop to cut away your extra area at the bottom of your logo. Or you can just use the Paint in Microsoft Windows to do it if you are using Windows.

Comment: It is always the best practice to show the images on your website exactly as how big they are with the original images you load from your files. That will make your website loads a bit faster because your program doesn't need to resize your images programmatically for you.

Comment: Than you so much :) That also fixes another two problems ive been having!

Comment: Hey man no problem! :) Good website!

Comment: Hi again ;) I was wondering could you help me with another problem? It is to do with my footer!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this image:

[image]

Just as stated by everybody, cropping your image is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

best solutions would be to crop image appropriately, but you can solve it with adding this css rule to your image:

```
overflow: hidden
```

notice this will hide part of the image, so if you have something under `Anime Database` it would be hidden.

Answer (score -1):

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```